# Rails 4 strong parameters with custom nested attributes name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, strong-parameters

I want to change the name of the attribute in strong parameter so it does not have "_attributes" in the end.

I have:

```
params.require(:setting).permit(:recording,
                               :special_settings_attributes => [:orientation])
```

I am testing it with :

```
  describe "Settings Creation" do

    context 'new setting success' do
      before do
        a = post :create, format: :json, :setting => {
          :recording => "recorded",
          :special_settings_attributes => [:orientation => "left"]
        }

      end

      it 'creates a new setting' do
        expect(Setting.last.special_settings.last.orientation).to eq("left")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I want

```
params.require(:setting).permit(:recording,
                               :special_settings => [:orientation])
```

I tried renaming of course, but then the SpecialSetting model is no created..

Comment: I would ask why?  This is out-of-the-box rails functionality for nested associations in forms.

Comment: for API calls so the parameters are a bit more human-friendly

Comment: Also in current setup it's easier to make some adjustments on server-side then on the calling side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just alter your `params` before it's called/used by any of your actions:

```
before_action do
  params[:special_settings_attributes] ||= params.delete :special_settings
end
```

Comment: thank you - only had to alter it to :

before_action do
  params[:setting][:special_settings_attributes] ||= params[:setting].delete :special_settings
end